# Jenkins makes iOS automatic packaging times wrong

Tags: ios, jenkins

I want to use Jenkins to implement the automatic packaging of iOS, but I have a problem，Does anybody know how to solve this

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Xcode _project_ or _Workspace_?

Comment: It's a project without cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Xcode project is that when the Schemes are not set to be 'Shared' then it is impossible to immediately after checkout run the xcodebuild command. If you have access to the source code then just go to the scheme management and set it to shared. If not, there is a workaround that requires 'xcodeproj' ruby gem and a little script:

```
require 'xcodeproj'
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open(ARGV[0])
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```

Hope it helps